# Nuget: The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 preview CTP 5 and I'm having problems installing *some* packages.

If I use the NPM UI I get

```
The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout.
```

If I use the PM Console with `Install-Package Ninject.MVC5` I get :

```
The source at nuget.org [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is unreachable. Falling back to NuGet Local Cache at {userfolder}\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Ninject.MVC5'.
```

If I type: `Install-Package Ninject.MVC5 -source nuget.org` i get the same UI error :

```
Install-Package : The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout.
```

I tryied this from other sources that points to solution but none worked.
I see a similar problem on nuget but a code 'fix' was release according to the github repo on January, 15.

I'm not sure if this is on my end or a nuget server problem, tryied to reach them at twitter with no response still, don't know what else to try.

Comment: Having the same problem over here on 2 different computers, both running vs2103. since yesterday.

Comment: Same problem with visual studio 2013 here. I think there is a problem on nuget servers.

Comment: The same problem with VS2013. I have also tried to restore packages using command line binary and the same error.

Comment: Same here.  Multiple members on my team are also having the same issue.  Our initial thought was that nuget is on Azure servers, which might have been hammered by SuperBowl traffic... but now it's had some time and it's still happening.

Comment: My displeasure with all things related to Microsoft is beginning to reach an all time high.

Comment: Same problem in vs 2013 for a packet I recently created when I try from work. No problems from home.

Comment: I have the same problem, from VS 2015 as well as from command line NuGet 2.8.2. But it's only for a few packages. E.g. "Bootstrap 3.2.0" always fails. Both at work and at home.

Comment: I republished an updated version of package that I was working on and it now installs correctly. Not sure if it is a fix on my end or Nugets...

Comment: I've been having frequent 504 Gateway Timeout problems with NuGet lately too. Seems to be related to DNS resolution.

Comment: This problem appears to be solved now, at least for me. I have undone my fix, and it's still working.

Comment: Had the same issue, and it turned out NuGet was literally just down, which one could figure out from Twitter posts (https://twitter.com/hashtag/NuGet?src=hash)

Answer (score 12):

I have found a workaround. Change the NuGet package source to use HTTP instead of HTTPS.

In Visual Studio (2015):
`Tools / NuGet Package Manager / Package Manager Settings`
Change the `Source` value of `nuget.org` from
`https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/`
to
`http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/`

If you're using the CLI, you can do the same by using the `nuget sources` command.

(This workaround obviously removes the encryption on your requests, so anyone sniffing will be able to see what packages you are downloading. Use at your own risk.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I still receive the same error.  EDIT - I have just found out via https://status.nuget.org/ that NuGet as a whole is down.  I guess that explains it.

Comment: this answer worked for me but I added this comment to give more details about changing the source using CLI: nuget sources (show all sources), nuget sources Add -Name "v3" -Source http://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json (Add new source called "v3"), nuget sources Disable -Name nuget.org (disable default source), dotnet restore

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, and after struggling for a couple of hours I finally got it.

There seems to be an issue with the later version of nuget source at url https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

To fix the issue...go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings, under Package Sources create a new package source
Name: NugetSource
Source: http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/

Move the newly created source to the top of the list under Available package sources. Click OK and restart Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm curious if this solution is still working. While it did work for me as of last week, it no longer is working for me now. I'm currently receiving the following error: Could not find a property named 'IsAbsoluteLatestVersion' on type 'NuGetGallery.V1FeedPackage'. 

The solution offered by MeMark does still appear to work though.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to use an HTTP proxy when installing NuGets.

Use for example ProxyDNS (http://proxydns.co/) by setting these in Windows `Network and Sharing Center => [select your network connection] => Properties => Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) => Properties => Use the following DNS server addresses`:

Preferred DNS server: 74.207.242.213

Alternate DNS server: 50.116.28.138

[image: proxy settings]

The reason this works (perhaps, I'm not a network expert) is that the problem seems so be some sort of name resolution (DNS) problem related to the content delivery network (CDN) that NuGet is using for hosting the packages.

For example, today I couldn't get xunit 2.0 installed and the reason is that https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/packages/xunit.assert.2.0.0-rc1-build2826.nupkg returned with (504) Gateway Timeout. If I use HTTP instead of HTTPS http://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/packages/xunit.assert.2.0.0-rc1-build2826.nupkg the package downloads OK.

I have used ProxyDNS to get around the problem and this has worked every time so far.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: I had to change network type from "Shared Network / NAT" to "Bridged" when trying to run NuGet inside a virtual machine (Parallels and macOS).

Answer (score 0):

thanks so much @MEMark and others

so I did following in CLI

```
dotnet new --nuget-source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ --install Amazon.Lambda.Templates::3.9.0
```

worked well